# How can I remove Change Owner button from Account object List View in Salesforce?

Tags: account, list-view, configuration

How can I remove the Change Owner button from Account object List View in Salesforce? I already tried looking into the [Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic --> List View] but didn't find anything to disable this button.

Comment: This may be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you trying to solve by disabling this button? Have you considered any alternatives to removing this button?

Comment: @sfdcfox - For now I have to use configuration to achieve this target. In the Account records we see a button "Change Owner", I want to hide/remove it from the UI. What I tried is already mentioned in the question description above.